# search substring + integer from a string in python using regular expression

Tags: python

I have a string 
`str="TMOUT=1800; export TMOUT"`

I want to extract only `TMOUT=1800` from above string, but `1800` is not constant it can be any integer value. For example `TMOUT=18` or `TMOUT=201` etc. I'm very new to regular expression.

I tried using code below

```
re.search("TMOUT=\d",str).
```

It is not working. Please help

Comment: `s.split(';')[0]`

Comment: @FHTMitchell OP isn't looking for the value `1800`. Why are you splitting on `"` there are none in the string?

Comment: Ah I see, I got confused by the `str=`. Of course they are looking for the value though, why else would the be doing this?

Answer (score 4):

`\d` matches a **single** digit. You want to match *one or more digits*, so you have to add a `+` quantifier:

```
re.search("TMOUT=\d+", text)
```

If you then you want to extract the number you have to create a group using parenthesis `()`:

```
match = re.search(r"TMOUT=(\d+)", text)
number = int(match.group(1))
```

Or you may want to use the named group syntax `(?P<name>)`:

```
match = re.search(r"TMOUT=(?P<num>\d+)", text)
number = int(match.group("num"))
```

---

I suggest you use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test your regexes and get an explanation of what they do. Also read [python's `re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to learn about the methods of the various objects and functions available.